# Oath 2.0 Why have tokens expire?

Tags: oauth-2.0

I am creating an Oath 2.0 system on my server allowing users to log into their account on my server from the app without having to give the username and password to the app itself. Which as I understand is the purpose of Oath, and it seems to work pretty well, the system is built on compliance with all Oath 2.0 specifications and is fully functional. But what I don't understand is why I have to have tokens expire... I mean I provide a refresh uri and they can easily at any time and at no cost renew the token (or get a new valid one). I dont see any purpose in this, why not just make the token never expire. I don't see the security benefits or any purpose for that matter for token expiration. Can someone explain to me why I have to have my tokens expire and why they can't just be good indefinitely?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a word, for more safe.

In your question, you said *at no cost renew the token*, actually, when you refresh token, you need to authenticate with the authorization server(provide your client credential). So refresh token is not equal with access token. It can not give you the access to resource.

Why have token expire?

As [OAuth 2.0 Threat Model and Security Considerations](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6819) says:

> 3.1.2.  Limited Access Token Lifetime

> The protocol parameter "expires_in" allows an authorization server
> (based on its policies or on behalf of the end user) to limit the
> lifetime of an access token and to pass this information to the
> client.  **This mechanism can be used to issue short-lived tokens to
> OAuth clients that the authorization server deems less secure, or
> where sending tokens over non-secure channels.**

> 5.1.5.2.  Determine Expiration Time

> Tokens should generally expire after a reasonable duration.  **This
> complements and strengthens other security measures (such as
> signatures) and reduces the impact of all kinds of token leaks.**
> Depending on the risk associated with token leakage, tokens may
> expire after a few minutes (e.g., for payment transactions) or stay
> valid for hours (e.g., read access to contacts).

Answer (score 0):

I found another use for it. When I store a token in my database at every login. If someone no longer uses a device or deletes their token (uninstalls an app or clears a cache) for any reason without properly "logging out" (logging out removes it from the database). Then there is a token stored on the database that will never be used again. After a while this becomes cumbersome taking up valuable space on the database and slowing down query executions for unused tokens. With token expirations I can run a cron job to scan the database for expired tokens every 15 minutes or so and remove them. Having to refresh tokens does put some strain on the server and the client but not as much as having potentially millions of unused tokens.